# Retrieve data from multiple tables from sqlite database titanium

Tags: database, sqlite, titanium, left-join

I was trying to retrieve data from multiple tables from sqlite database with titanium  using select statement with left join property.

It retrieves null or undefined and I used this statement with sqlite administrator, it retrieves data.
You can check my code:

```
var db = Ti.Database.install('Path/DB_Name.s3db', 'DB_Name');
var rows = db.execute(
     'select c.CustomerID,c.Name, c.CustomerCode,v.ConfirmationDate  from  Customer as c' +
     ' left join Visits as v on c.CustomerID==v.CustomerID ' +
     '  order by  v.ConfirmationDate desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
var db = Ti.Database.install('Path/DB_Name.s3db', 'DB_Name');
var rows = db.execute(
 'select c.CustomerID,c.Name, c.CustomerCode,v.ConfirmationDate  from  Customer as c' +
 ' left join Visits as v on c.CustomerID=v.CustomerID ' +
 '  order by  v.ConfirmationDate desc');
```

Single "="

Comment: Hello Jeroen, thanks for your reply but it doesn't work.

Comment: Still false or an error ? Does a simple select without a join return any data ?

Comment: not false and also not error, it shows undefined i don't know the reason.
I tried the simple statement it return zero result although the select statement worked on sqlite administrator :(

Comment: What exactly is returning false, is it the var rows ?
Can you show your database structure + is the titanium log giving any useful errors ?